# Unbind default button behavior in wxPython

Tags: python, events, user-interface, binding, wxpython

I am writing an interface where I'd like to have a user click a button, then capture his next keystroke.

I can currently capture all the keys on the keyboard, except for those like tab or the arrow keys which cause the button to lose focus when pressed. I know that I need to unbind the window from keypress events during the capture interval.

I've already tried unbinding from the frame, the notebook tab widget, and the panel that's inside it, and it has not worked.

Where in the hierarchy do I need to unbind key presses to avoid having them behave the way they normally do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import wx 

a = wx.App(redirect=False)
class XFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args)
        b = wx.Button(self,-1,"Click")
        b.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnButton)
    def OnButton(self,evt):
        self.SetFocus()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR,self.OnChar)
    def OnChar(self,evt):
        print evt.KeyCode
        self.Unbind(wx.EVT_CHAR)

f = XFrame(None,-1,"A Frame")

f.Show()
a.MainLoop()
```

I think anyway

Comment: Ha! It never occurred to me to bind the keypress event to the window itself. Thank you! My code has been modified and runs beautifully now.